# Match jquery function by reqular expression in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a file which has jquery codes into the head section, like following..

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.x').click(function(){
        // some thing
    });
    $('.y').click(function(){
        // some thing
    });
});
</script>
</head>
```

I want to use PHP to read the file and retrieve the content that are located inside the `$(document).ready(function(){` section by using regular expression like `preg_match_all`. More specifically saying I need the two `.click` functions. Purpose is academic only. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If this is academic, is there a margin of error you're allowed?  Since you're singling out `preg_match_all`, is there a specified way you to split up the data you're extracting from the string?

Comment: Actually I need to get the data, then put the data into a **.js** file. After that i include the newly created **.js** file.

Comment: Can you expect that the document ready code is the only JS outermost code in the `<head>` tag (which, should really be in a `<script>` tag)?

Comment: Yes Erutan409. All I have inside `<script>` tag is `$(document) bla bla });`. Each jquery code is placed inside it.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
\$\((?!document\).ready).*?\}\);
```

Here's what this expression does:

- `\$\(` - This looks for a literal dollar sign `$` followed by an opening parenthesis `(`.
- `(?!document\).ready)` - This is a negative lookahead that says `document).ready` cannot be following the `$(`.
- `.*?` - The dot `.` allows any character to be matched, the asterisk `*` allows that character to be matched any number of times and the question mark `?` makes it ungreedy and tells it to stop matching when it hits the next part of the expression.  The closing brackets.
- `\}\);` - This final part is simply the closing tags. It's going to use a literal closing curly brace `}`, followed by a closing parenthesis `)` and a semicolon `;` to be the end of the string.

Of course, since you are matching so many REGEX reserved characters, we end up with five slashes.

Anyway, if you take that an put it into a `preg_match_all` context, you'd end up with something like this:

```
preg_match_all('~\$\((?!document\).ready).*?\}\);~sim', $string, $matches);
print "<pre>"; print_r($matches[0]); print "</pre>";
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => $('.x').click(function(){
        // some thing
    });
    [1] => $('.y').click(function(){
        // some thing
    });
)
```

Here is a working demo.
http://ideone.com/R1t5P5

Answer (score 0):

See [this regex](http://bit.ly/1moCZGl):

```
<head>\s*<script> # Anchor your regex to these tags
  \s*\$\(\h*document\h*\)\.ready\( # Match the beginning statement
    ([\S\s]+) # Grab the content you want
  \);\s* # Match the ending statement
<\/script> # Anchor the last closing tag to prevent over-matching
```

So, everything you want is inside the first capture group.  This is a dirty way of getting your content, but based on your aforementioned assurances of no varying content, this should work fine.

Comment: You don't need the `g` or `m` modifiers.  If you keep the indenting/newlines in the regex, you're going to want to use `x`, for sure.

Comment: Very good approach. Thank you. But I want a set or an array, each function will be stored as an element. You brought me total string.

Comment: I need `$('.x').click` and `$('.y').click` separated, not in a single string.